# How can I calculate the date of the upcoming second Monday in January relative to the current date in SQL?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

How can I calculate the date of the upcoming second Monday in January relative to the current date using a SQL query?

Below is a query that I have which doesn't work if the current date is of the same year but prior to the upcoming second Monday of January.

```
declare @secondMondayOfJan date = dateadd(day , ((17 - datepart(dw,current_timestamp)) % 7) + 6, current_timestamp)

IF current_timestamp > @secondMondayOfJan
select @secondMondayOfJan as Deadline
ELSE
declare @firstDayOfNextYear date = datefromparts(year(current_timestamp)+1,1,1) 

set @secondMondayOfJan = dateadd(day, ((17 - datepart(dw,@firstDayOfNextYear)) % 7) + 6, @firstDayOfNextYear)   
select @secondMondayOfJan as Deadline
```

Comment: Are trying to get the number of days until the second Monday in January?  Or the date of the next second Monday in January?  I ask because the latter wouldn't depend on the current date on the server, other than to know whether the current date is before or after the second Monday in January.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks quite verbose, but hopefully makes the logic *clear*, and doesn't depend on any particular settings (such as `DATEFIRST` or language settings):

```
;With Nums(n) as (
    select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
             union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
), ThisAndNext as (
    select
        DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010108') as SecondWeek,
        0 as Choose
    union all
    select
        DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20020108'),
        1
), Combined as (
    select DATEADD(day,n,SecondWeek) as Possible,Choose
    from ThisAndNext cross join Nums
)
select top 1 Possible from Combined
where Possible >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
and DATEPART(weekday,Possible) = DATEPART(weekday,'20150504')
order by Choose
```

`Nums` is just a small set of numbers - it can be replaced with a select from a numbers table, if you already have one.

`ThisAndNext` finds the 8th of this year and next year, as two separate rows.

`Combined` adds between 0 and 6 days onto the 8th of this year and next.

Finally, we select the first date from `Combined` that is (the following bullet points correspond to the lines of the `WHERE` clause)

- equal to or greater than today's date (using another instance of the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pattern to remove the time element from `GETDATE()`)
- on a Monday (by comparing it to an arbitrary, well known Monday)
- by preference, from this year rather than next

All taken together, this means that we have selected a future (or current) day that falls between the 8th and the 14th of January that is a Monday. If you don't want "today" to be a possible result, just change the `>=` comparison towards the end to be a `>`.

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind this code is:

- get the first day of the current year
- get the first day of the next year
- find the 2nd weekday of jan of the current year
- find the 2nd weekday of jan of the next year
- compare the current date if is greater than or less than or equal and based on this set the deadline to the correct 2nd weekday

It's setup to retrieve the 2nd monday, but changing the value of the variable `@dw` between 1 to 7, you will get the others weekday
(1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, 3 = Tuesday, 4 = Wednesday, 5 = Thursday, 6 = Friday, 7 = Saturday)

You can play with this code at:
http://rextester.com/TVKYW75798

```
/*
THIS STATEMENT WILL RETURN THE 2ND WEEKDAY OF JAN BASED ON CURRENT DATE.

IF CURRENT_DATE = 2ND WEEKDAY OF JAN 
    THEN DEADLINE = CURRENT_DATE

IF CURRENT_DATE < 2ND WEEKDAY OF JAN
    THEN DEADLINE = 2ND WEEKDAY OF JAN (CURRENT YEAR)

IF CURRENT_DATE > 2ND WEEKDAY OF JAN
    THEN DEADLINE = 2ND WEEKDAY OF JAN (NEXT YEAR)


YOU CAN PLAY WITH VARIABLE @date and @dw TO TEST. 

I LEAVE COMMENTED IN THE CODE FOUR SCENARIOS (YEAR 2015) 
WHERE YOU WILL BE ABLE TO CHECK THE CONDITIONS ABOVE.

2015-01-12 WAS THE 2ND MONDAY OF JAN
*/

DECLARE @date DATE = GETDATE() 
-- SET @date = '2015-01-01'
-- SET @date = '2015-01-11'
-- SET @date = '2015-01-12'
-- SET @date = '2015-01-13'

DECLARE @currentYearFirstDay DATE = CAST(datepart(yy, @date) AS VARCHAR) + '-01-01'
DECLARE @nextYearFirstDay DATE = DATEADD(yy, 1, @currentYearFirstDay)

DECLARE @d DATE
DECLARE @secondWeekdayCurrentYear DATE
DECLARE @secondWeekdayNextYear DATE

DECLARE @dw INT = 2 /*USE VALUES FROM 1 TO 7, WHERE 1 = SUNDAY AND 7 = SATURDAY*/
DECLARE @weekOfYear INT = DATEPART(ww,@d)
DECLARE @weekDay INT = DATEPART(dw,@d)

DECLARE @checkNextYear INT = 0
SET @d = @currentYearFirstDay

GOTO GET_2nd_WEEKDAY_FROM_FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR  


GET_2nd_WEEKDAY_FROM_FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR:
BEGIN   
    SET @weekDay = DATEPART(dw, @d)
    /*FIRST DAY OF YEAR GREATER THAN WEEKDAY, THEN 2nd WEEKDAY WILL BE THE 3rd WEEK*/
    IF @weekDay > @dw
        BEGIN
            SET @d = DATEADD(ww, 2, @d)
        END
    /*FIRST DAY OF YEAR LESS THAN OR EQUAL WEEKDAY, THEN 2nd WEEKDAY WILL BE THE 2nd WEEK*/    
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @d = DATEADD(ww, 1, @d)
        END
    IF @checkNextYear = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @secondWeekdayCurrentYear = DATEADD(dw, -(@weekDay - @dw), @d)
            SET @d = @nextYearFirstDay
            SET @checkNextYear = 1
            GOTO GET_2nd_WEEKDAY_FROM_FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @secondWeekdayNextYear = DATEADD(dd, -(@weekDay - @dw), @d)
            GOTO EXIT_BLOCK
        END
END

EXIT_BLOCK:
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN @date > @secondWeekdayCurrentYear 
               THEN @secondWeekdayNextYear
               ELSE
                   CASE 
                       WHEN @date = @secondWeekdayCurrentYear
                           THEN @date
                           ELSE @secondWeekdayCurrentYear
                    END
      END AS DEADLINE
```